# Iterate with List(mylist.size){ index -> TODO()} or Map in kotlin Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, generics, collections, maps

I found this code and I would like know which is more efficient to big lists of elements.

```
return List(myBigList.size){ index ->
   val element = myBigList[index]
   myConversionFunction(element,param2,param3,param4)
}
```

I though this code could be replaced by

```
return myBigList.map{
    myConversionFunction(it,param2,param3,param4)
}
```

Which way is better if I have a lot of elements to iterate, or you suggest other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both options are just as efficient, you should use the clearest one, which is the second option.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a big list you should consider to not use List, because it's load everything in memory. In kotlin consider using Sequences (aka streams in Java) https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html#from-an-iterable which is lazily by nature and avoid loading every element of your "big list" in memory.

Comment: myBigList.asSequence().map{
    myConversionFunction(it,param2,param3,param4)
}.toList()

Something Like this?

Comment: The list is already in memory, it makes no sense to convert to a sequence and then back to a list if there is just this transformation operation. It's only useful to do this if you can process elements one by one, or short-circuit the process in some way, and never store the whole resulting list.

Comment: Oftentimes that isn’t an option or doesn’t help because you are working with data already loaded in memory or that must be displayed to the user.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Exactly the data is already in memory, I have to change all code application to operate with sequence, and I have to made a hotfix.

Comment: It's still worth considering this option if you do not want a *second* big list that is stored in memory in its entirety. Depending on the use case a sequence as an alternative for the transformed list may be much more efficient.